# Problem getting the right raster image text

Tags: javascript, object, html5-canvas, fabricjs, raster

I am using canvas to place fabric objects on it and generate png image file and/or layered pdf file (depending upon user choice)

This is my code:

```
function copy2_temp_canvas(){
    let vobjects = canvas.getObjects();

    for (let i = 0; i < vobjects.length; i++) {
        vobjects[i].clone(function(objcloned) {
            temp_canvas.add(objcloned.set({
                left: 0, 
                top: 0
            })).renderAll();
        });
    }
    base64_of_temp_canvas();
}

function base64_of_temp_canvas(){
    let objbase64 = temp_canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 1});
    document.getElementById('rasterimg').value = objbase64;
}
```

The problem is when I call the function `base64_of_temp_canvas()` from within function `copy2_temp_canvas()` body it generates wrong raster image text and i get no image in png/pdf file in result .On the other hand,  when i call both functions `copy2_temp_canvas()` and `base64_of_temp_canvas()` separately / manually it gives right raster text and i get right image.

What should I do to get right raster image text by calling function `base64_of_temp_canvas()` from function `copy2_temp_canvas()` body ?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by _wrong raster image_? Is it completely blank? 2. What's the fabricjs version that you're using?

Comment: yes, its complete blank and fabric version i am using is 3.6.0